# How to make QDockWidgets as separate windows?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdockwidget

I have a Qt application with some `QDockWidgets`, which can be docked and undocked with these features:

- `DockWidgetFloatable`
- `DockWidgetMovable`
- `DockWidgetVerticalTitleBar`
- `DockWidgetClosable`

I would like to use the window layout manager of Windows (like using a split screen of the docked widgets and the main application). But it's not possible now because the docked widgets are still child windows of the main application.

Is there a flag I can set to make them as separate windows?

Comment: Okay so my question to you is why are you creating Dockable windows if that is not what you want -- if what you are wanting are stand alone windows than create QWidgets or some other type of Window Object for these tertiary windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> flags Qt::WindowFlagsflags Qt::WindowFlags - **Qt::Window**
>
> Indicates that the widget is a window, usually with a window system frame and a title bar, irrespective of whether the widget has a parent or not. Note that it is not possible to unset this flag if the widget does not have a parent.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Dockdemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dockdemo, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Dock demo")
        self.setCentralWidget(QTextEdit())

        items      = QDockWidget("Dockable", self, flags=Qt.Window)  # flags=Qt.Window
#        items.setGeometry(650, 130, 300, 200)
        items.show()                                                 # +++

        listWidget = QListWidget()
        listWidget.addItem("item1")
        listWidget.addItem("item2")
        listWidget.addItem("item3")
        items.setWidget(listWidget)
        items.setFloating(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Dockdemo()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]